# Centering a form within a div

Tags: html, css

I have a simple contact form within a div but I can't get it to center within the div. I have tried margins, padding, text-align:center but none of them work.

html: http://www.joekellywebdesign.com/churchsample/contact.html

```
<div id="contactbottomright">
        <h2>Contact Form</h2>

    <form action="feedback.php" method="post">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="8">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="tswname">Name</label>:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="fullname" id="tswname" size="25" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="tswemail">Email address</label>:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="tswemail" name="email" size="25" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <label for="tswcomments">Comments</label>
                    <br />
                    <textarea rows="15" cols="35" name="comments" id="tswcomments"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

css: http://www.joekellywebdesign.com/churchsample/css/styles.css

```
/* rules for contact page */

#contactbottomleft {z-index:26; width:450px;height: 700px; background-color:#92B681; margin: 30px 0 0 0; float:left;position: relative;}

#contactbottomright { z-index:27; width:450px; height: 700px; margin: 30px 0 0 0px; background-color:#428C3E; float:right;position: relative;}

form {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

    /* end rules for contact page */
```

Comment: duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=centering+div

Comment: Sorry to undo all your hard work, but you can just highlight the entire code and click on the `{}` button to add code formatting, instead of adding backticks to every single line.

Comment: @Juhana I had no idea that did that.  Soooo many times I've wanted that, haha.  Thanks!

Comment: I've tried everything in those other post and it doesn't work. Setting width then margin, setting padding. assigning specific margins, etc...

Comment: @ Juhana. when I try to do that it still wants to initiate it as code instead of listing the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set a width to the form and then add `margin: 0 auto;` to the CSS. For example:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <form></form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}
```

NOTE: For this to work, you must remove `display:inline-block` from `form`.

[JS Fiddle Example (using your HTML/CSS)](http://jsfiddle.net/LBqbP/2/).

Comment: @JoeElmore Remove line104 `display: inline-block;`

Comment: @JoeElmore Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBqbP/) showing this answer in action.

Comment: Actually it did work. I had to remove my other formatting that I had in for form. Thank you. It's not letting me accept the answer yet. I will do so and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You must set a Width of Ancestor element and then add `margin:0 auto` to its child.
See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zQFfc/)